# What are the Gotchas and Issues I should be aware of with SFML?

Tags: sfml

I've been using SDL for a while to prototype small things and to learn more about graphics programming.

Then I saw [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org) and wanted to give it a try, saw that it was more object oriented and fixed some issues I felt SDL had.

But since I know little about the library itself, what are it's main flaws and other issues that I should be aware of?

Currently I'm liking it, good tutorial and most things just seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest issue that has ever affected me is [the crash involving the default font when ending a program](http://www.sfml-dev.org/todo/index.php?do=details&task_id=152).  This is a fairly well-known bug that you can read about in the [SFML forums](http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/index.php).  As far as I know, this bug is fixed for the 2.0 version of SFML but not for 1.x versions.

For other bugs (along with feature requests), you can check out the [SFML Roadmap](http://www.sfml-dev.org/todo/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, now SFML 2.x is quite standard.

I have 2 main issues with 2.1:

- The program can crash when ending with Windows XP, because of a bug in the audio module.
  It should be corrected now, but not in the 2.1 and the fix is out of scope for the 2.2 (to come) version.
  -> You can compile the last SFML version, or use something else for Audio (OpenAL, SDL...).
- RenderTextures don't work correctly on Mac : I haven't found any workaround, so I just don't use RenderTextures now.